# How to specify generics in an array if interfaces in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, generics

I have a function that takes an array of specifications as an argument. The shape of these specifications are defined, but the values can be anything. However - I'd like to provide a generic to let TypeScript infer the types based on the specs I pass into the function. Here's a very basic example:

```js
interface Spec<YourType> {
    value: YourType;
}

function doStuff<T>(specs: Spec<T>[]): T[] {
    return specs.map(spec => spec.value);
}

const mySpecs = [
    {value: 1},
    {value: 'two'},
    {value: [1, 2, 3]},
];

const values = doStuff(mySpecs);
```

I understand it can't really infer types here because they're all different, but can I somehow add them as types explicitly to the doStuff generic. Something like this pseudo-code:

```
function doStuff<T>(specs: <Spec<t> for t of T>): <t for t of T> {
    return specs.map(spec => spec.value);
}

const values = doStuff<[number, string, number[]]>(mySpecs);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript 3.1 introduced support for using [mapped tuple types](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays), so if you have a type like `[1,2,3]` and apply a mapped type like `{[K in keyof T]: Spec<T[K]>}` to it, it will become `[Spec<1>, Spec<2>, Spec<3>]`.  Therefore the signature for your function could be something like this:

```
declare function doStuff<T extends readonly any[]>(
  specs: { [K in keyof T]: Spec<T[K]> } | []
): T;
```

That's fairly close to your pseudo-code.  The only differences of note is that we are saying that `T` has to be either an `Array` or `ReadonlyArray` (a `ReadonlyArray` is considered a wider type than `Array`), and the `specs` parameter's type has a union with an empty tuple type `| []` in there to [give the compiler a hint](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27179#issuecomment-422606990) that it should infer `T` to be a tuple type if possible, instead of just an order-forgetting array.  Here's what usages would look like:

```
const values = doStuff([
  { value: 1 },
  { value: 'two' },
  { value: [1, 2, 3] },
]);
// const values: [number, string, number[]]
```

If you want to do that in two separate lines with `mySpecs` you should probably tell the compiler not to forget that `mySpecs` is a tuple type, like this:

```
const mySpecs = [
  { value: 1 },
  { value: 'two' },
  { value: [1, 2, 3] },
] as const;
/* const mySpecs: readonly [
  { readonly value: 1; }, { readonly value: "two"; }, { readonly value: readonly [1, 2, 3];
}] */

const moreValues = doStuff(mySpecs);
// const moreValues: readonly [1, "two", readonly [1, 2, 3]]
```

Here I've used a TypeScript 3.4+ [`const` assertion](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) to keep the type of `mySpecs` narrow...  maybe it's *too* narrow since everything becomes `readonly` and [literal types](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types).  But that's up to you to work with.

---

This would be the end of the answer except that, unfortunately, the compiler cannot verify that the implementation of `doStuff()` conforms to the signature:

```
return specs.map(spec => spec.value); // error! not callable
```

The easiest way around this is to use some judicious [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) to convince the compiler first that `specs` has a usable `map` method (by saying it's a `Spec<any>[]` instead of just `T`, and that the output is indeed a `T`:

```
function doStuff<T extends readonly any[]>(specs: { [K in keyof T]: Spec<T[K]> } | []): T {
  return (specs as Spec<any>[]).map(spec => spec.value) as readonly any[] as T;
}
```

That compiles now and should be close to what you're looking for.  Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoAcIIDwE0D2ArlACoCemAfMgN4BQyyAbnADaEQBcyBx5mAbjoBfOnRiEQCMMHwhkAE3yowhGDGwlkEAB6QQCgM7IoEOEpCsyyOCDIBtALqUAFIcwJD3GsnsBpZFBkAGsIMnwYZBJHbgwsTX9nZGFkAB9fRwBKbi16RlNVKHk3D2M4YzicWzJKJ0yAOgBbOHQSrGQAXmp3LHqWdghMm2NTczkrGzsnYaihUQY6BDlDMGY2DmMOxWVVdRd7Blo1ge4ARmSAGkOffo5uAHIwAHd8e8vr47vfU4vkACZfgBmRzvLJCAD04OQSxAK0+EC8vhAhEaACNoL8VlBQABzX7ItHQJyOMRiGFwxpkSqbXwfW5cZDnYRXRg3dYMx4vN7Muns7j2H7-IEgnkg8rQ5ZgCEAKglsNWlOp3FGFgmB1ZJjMqus9LOAkuRxV4x1fOQACJnvgzfrmYatcb4cr7ZZrALfgDkMC5iDpeCyZLkI18KYAGrsmlKFRqGAuRWlTIQqHkhXBiBhgaIo0u76-C0vM2-LNqwUe4EkuhAA)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to provide union type definition of `YourType` to make it work:

```
const mySpecs = [
    {value: 1},
    {value: 'two'},
    {value: [1, 2, 3]},
];

type YourType = number | string | number[];

interface Spec<YourType> {
    value: YourType;
}

function doStuff<T>(specs: Spec<T>[]): T[] {
    return specs.map(spec => spec.value);
}

const values = doStuff<YourType>(mySpecs);
console.log(values);
```